# How does iOS 13 Safari link preview work?

Tags: ios, wkwebview, ios13

In iOS 13 Safari, when you long press on a link, you see a preview of the linked page, along with some menu items. If you tap the preview, you navigate to that page.

Now, I see how to intervene in the long-press-and-preview process. This used to be peek-and-pop, but in iOS 13 that's deprecated and we're supposed to use `func webView(_:contextMenuConfigurationForElement:)` and so forth. Fine, but how would I imitate what Safari does?

The problem is that as my preview provider I have to supply a view controller. So I'm going to need a different view controller with a web view showing the linked page. Okay, I can do that. But then when the user taps the preview to dismiss it, I want to respond by loading the same linked page into my real web view.

But that's the problem. That loading takes time. In Safari, by contrast, when you tap the preview, boom, there's the same page already loaded. *How do they do that?* How would I do the same thing? How can I load the page into a different view controller, *cache* it, and communicate that cached page back to my real web view?

Comment: I think, they replace current view controller with other view controller with preloaded page ( they can use same view controller, what you can see as a preview or other invisible view controller). Without replacing you will see a page reloading.

Comment: I agree - It looks like they actually resize the preview view controller and replace the existing view controller - Much as you did with the old peek & pop method - The deep press "committed" the view controller that was being previewed.

Comment: @Paulw11  they can’t be replacing the existing view controller because Back works afterward. It’s like they are able to share the cache between web views. But all my attempts to do that have failed.

Comment: Well, maybe not replacing the view controller, maybe just replacing the view.  Remember, this is Apple; they don't have to play by the same rules.  Who knows what access they have to the internals of WebKit.